# Jboss AS7 + CAS - in all applications

Tags: jboss, single-sign-on, cas

I have Jboss AS7 and CAS deployed and working.

Also I have a test application deployed "Hello World" and I need to integrate this with CAS. I mean I want to request a login through CAS to acces this app.

So, after this I need to configure this to work something like: I'll have more applications and I want to be able to login in one of my application through CAS and then, even if I change applications, it will remember me.

Can someone tell me how can I do this?

This is my web.xml:

```
    <web-app id="simple" version="2.4">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>hello.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>

<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>All resources</web-resource-name>
            <description>Protects all resources</description>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>*</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
              org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.Saml11AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
              <param-name>casServerLoginUrl</param-name>
              <param-value>https://127.0.0.1:8443/cas/login</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>serverName</param-name>
        <param-value>http://127.0.0.1</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Saml11TicketValidationFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
              <param-name>casServerUrlPrefix</param-name>
              <param-value>https://127.0.0.1:8443/cas</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
              <param-name>serverName</param-name>
              <param-value>https://127.0.0.1:8443/cas</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
              <param-name>redirectAfterValidation</param-name>
              <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
              <param-name>tolerance</param-name>
              <param-value>1000</param-value>
        </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.util.HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS Assertion Thread Local Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.util.AssertionThreadLocalFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS Assertion Thread Local Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

UPDATE: After doing your instructions, i get this error when I try to deploy:

```
12:17:21,765 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "test.war"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS018096: Error instantiating container component: authenticator.CasAuthenticator
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WarDeploymentProcessor.getInstance(WarDeploymentProcessor.java:386)
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WarDeploymentProcessor.processDeployment(WarDeploymentProcessor.java:210)
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WarDeploymentProcessor.deploy(WarDeploymentProcessor.java:114)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: authenticator.CasAuthenticator from [Module "deployment.test.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WarDeploymentProcessor.getInstance(WarDeploymentProcessor.java:378)
        ... 8 more

12:17:21,770 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 16) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "test.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"test.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"test.war\".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"test.war\""}}
12:17:21,771 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (HttpManagementService-threads - 16) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "test.war"

12:17:21,775 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-9) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment test.war in 3ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one https://github.com/serac/java-cas-client-test & check the differences if its only for hello world proposes...

Answer (score 1):

Define your login-module in the standalone.xml:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2">
        <security-domain name="cas" cache-type="default">
            <authentication>
                <login-module code="authenticator.CasLoginModule" flag="required" module="jasig">
                    <module-option name="ticketValidatorClass" value="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Saml11TicketValidator"/>
                    <module-option name="casServerUrlPrefix" value="https://localhost:8443/cas"/>
                    <module-option name="roleGroupName" value="Roles"/>
                    <module-option name="defaultRoles" value="FOOBAR"/>
                    <module-option name="roleAttributeNames" value="Roles"/>
                </login-module>
            </authentication>
        </security-domain>
```

You have already defined your CAS security filters in the web.xml, thats enough and should work.

Are you using CAS protocol between apps and server or CAS? Is your Jasig configured to use SAML 1.1. By default, jasig will use CAS.

If your configuration already works, you should be able to SSO. Did you create a second helloworld to test it?

For reauthentication in other applications, you are redirecting to your CAS server, which already knows that the user is authenticated. So finally, he will redirect him to the application again and provide a CAS ticket.

Comment: So I did what you said (thank you by the way), I get that error. Can you please help me?

Comment: You are already using the CAS-Filter to secure your application, so you don't need an Authenticator, as CasAuthenticator was meant as a dummy class.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. You must understand that i started this yesterday just following steps I found here and there. I managed to deploy my cas.war. Now, deleting jboss-web.xml it worked as a charm (deployment), but when I access https://127.0.0.1:8443/test it doesn't redirect me to CAS. I don't have another application yet, because I'm not there yet. I think it should redirect me to login first. So, what file do you want me to show you to see what's wrong? Please...

Comment: Yes, it should redirect you to the jasig server. Can you access and login on the jasig server itself by calling the jasig URL? Did you try to debug your application and set a breakpoint in the invoke method of Saml11AuthenticationFilter?

Comment: Yes, if I try to access https://127.0.0.1:8443/cas it works, it goes to login page. I now have 2 Hello Worlds and none of them redirects me to CAS login page, even after writing that web.xml

Comment: Is * a valid role-name? Can you put your "hello world" on github?

Comment: https://github.com/valHALLuh/hello-world
Thank you so much for your help. I don't actually know what's that *. I haven't configured anything.

Comment: Do you have a complete maven project? Did you put the cas-client-jars into WAR/lib?

Comment: In git i put my entire Hello World project. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you miss all the libaries, where should your WAR find the filter-classes?

Comment: Is there a document, or something, like an example, for me to use, because I sincerely don't know how to do it and I really need to?

Comment: I added in my test.war in lib folder: cas-client-core-3.3.3, commons-codec-1.10, commons-logging-1.2, log4j-1.2.17, opensaml-2.6.4, xmlsec-2.0.4 and it still doesn't redirect me to cas login page. What am I doing wrong now?

Comment: I'll try to make a sample for you today.

Comment: Thank you so much. Man, how can I ever repay you :)

Comment: That link that bogdanbrudiu gave me works (that example), but I think that's because it has more links (the page). Comparing the web.xml from both, that's the only difference i see (I think). If you already started my example, can you please continue, because I want to see how could my helloworld work. Thank you so much @Martin Baumgartner

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81651/discussion-between-martin-baumgartner-and-robert).